# Security of Data and flaws in Android Application at OS level

Tags: android, security

I have started looking into what kind of security flaws that can be possible in Android.
Can u please share your views on what could be possible.

At OS level i have found

1> Buffer overflow on memory block.

Can u please share what could be the other scenario...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main articles in scientific world about that:

http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-09/BURNS/BHUSA09-Burns-AndroidSurgery-PAPER.pdf

http://www.cs.rice.edu/~sc40/pubs/enck-sec11.pdf

Moreover [here](http://css.csail.mit.edu/6.858/2012/readings/android.pdf) you can find article about Android security itself.

And a [presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1pYCuhTJrE) of Burns.